# FIWARE KeyRock access token request error on iOS client implementation

Tags: ios, oauth, fiware

I'm trying to request a KeyRock access token via iOS OAuth2 implementation.

In iOS the callback url on OAuth is not a regular `http://` url but is something like `myapp://oauth/callback`. The url for the authorization request is the following:

https://account.lab.fiware.org/oauth2/authorize/?response_type=code&client_id=123&redirect_uri=myapp://oauth/callback

After calling the url, I can login on the Fiware account, authorized my app, but instead of being redirected to my callback address **myapp://oauth/callback**, I always get the following error:

> Error: An error occurred when trying to obtain the authorization code.

I can't get my access token and I'm stuck on this page:

[image: Error page]

If I try to change the callback url, using a normal http:// address, everything works fine but on iOS that kind of url is unusable as callback in OAuth authentication.

What's wrong?

Comment: Hi, we had a bug in the custom schemas support. We have just fixed it. It will be available in the next deployment of FIWARE Lab portal. Many thanks for the report! :)

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer but I still get the same error. Does it take much time for the deployment?

Comment: @Valdis The fix now works for me, witch error do you get?

Comment: @FrancescoFiori issue was in our code, sorry for bothering